# Ant key in build.properties not appearing when run via Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, ant, properties, build.xml

I have a build.xml file that works with a build.properties file.

The build.properties file has 2 keys as below:

```
my.relativeurlpath=sample/web/${my.key}
my.key=default
```

I have a Jenkins job that writes the value of **my.key** in the build.properties file from an input parameter using a Shell script:

```
sed -i -e '/my\.key/d' build.properties
echo  "my.key = ${input_param}" >> build.properties
```

In my build.properties file, among other things, I create a properties file dynamically that reads my.key from the build.properties file:

```
<propertyfile file="myfile.properties">
            <entry key="SpecialKey" value="${my.key}" />
</propertyfile>
```

When I run the Jenkins job, the entry **my.relativeurlpath=sample/web/${my.key}** does not appear in build.properties file. As a result, the dynamically generated myfile.properties file does not receive the value for SpecialKey.

Could someone tell me how I can fix this? I suspect a circular reference is likely, but cannot settle with a clear view of it.

Comment: First, make sure you write and read from the same build.properties and doesn't replace it in between. Second check in you jenkins log if your `echo` code is being called at all.

Comment: Your build may be sensitive to working directory?  What happens if when you build from some other directory with ant -f <path to build file>.  In any case running ant -debug will dump lot of information about "property values"..